# How can I remove the magnifying glass in featherlight lightbox?

Tags: lightbox, featherlight.js

Where can I find the code in featherlight lightbox that enables the looking glass/magnifying glass? I wish to disable it and just have the normal mouse pointer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the necessary CSS to target what you want and set the [cursor how you want it](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Thanks you very much!